# What would cause a fetch API in Javascript to reject and catch an error? "Failed to fetch"

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm aware that fetch api will either go into catch or return with response.ok as false. In my case, (I believe) we consistently get to catch statement in our code and I'm trying to figure out what might be the issue.

Just to specify, fetch I'm talking about:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

While there are a lot of answers in regards to how one should also pay attention to checking response.ok, there is not much answers for what might cause the fetch to go into catch statement.

We specifically get the error as `Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Some of the reasons I've seen online for going to catch statement are:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin not matching
- connection error?
- timeout?

Thanks

Comment: What’s in the network tab?

Comment: These are from user logs, I'm not able to repro on my machine.

Comment: Only a [network error](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error) and an [abortion](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#abort-fetch) can cause fetch to reject. But that will probably not help you much. Can you tell us more about that request? Could it get blocked by some strict firewall?

Comment: I have tried to repro locally with strict firewall and browser security settings but haven't had any luck. I'll update the thread if I find any more information but thank you!